# Perform animation on a page after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing maintenance work for a website. The logo on the [home page](http://www.shiftus.in) is supposed to bounce in from left after page has loaded but the animation begins even when the page is still loading.

The code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#logo-large').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
  });
```

The site is using animate.css library

Comment: did you try adding delay to it? `$('#logo-large').delay(500).addClass('animated bounceInLeft');`

Comment: @odedta If the other resources e.g. the image itself take more time than 500 ms then it will not work.

Comment: Then he can set a value that will always work, other than that he needs to make sure his code is validated or just read from the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

The `ready` method do not wait for resources to load.

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Use `window.load` method:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#logo-large').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
});
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you say "page loaded" but you haven't defined what that means. The animation is, indeed, playing after the DOM has loaded. That's what the $(document).ready method insures. However, any images or asynchronous calls can still trigger after the DOM is ready. So... the REAL question is, do you want to wait til after the images have loaded AND do you have any asynchronous calls that need to be accounted for.

I just wrote this so I'm not 100% sure if it doesn't have any bugs, but this should work for both cases.

```
jQuery.prototype.pageComplete = function(promises, callback){
    if(!callback){
        callback = promises;
        promises = [];
    }

    var images = jQuery.Deferred();
    var DOMReady = jQuery.Deferred();
    var count = this.length;

    promises.push(images);
    promises.push(DOMReady);

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        DOMReady.resolve();
    });

    function counter(){
        if(--count == 0) images.resolve();
    }

    this.each(function(image){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = counter;
        img.src = image.src;
    });

    jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, promises).then(callback);
};
```

You use it like so:

```
// for just images
$('img').pageComplete(function(){
    // code to transition image here
});

 // for images and ajax
$('img').pageComplete([
        ajax1, // these are all promises created by jQuery.ajax
        ajax2,
        ajax3
    ],
    function(){
    // code to transition image here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, solution should work without jquery

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('logo-large').classList.add('animated', 'bounceInLeft');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use The Window Load Function**

This will wait until the whole page has loaded before running the animation

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $('#logo-large').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
});)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```